# Atom (for Mac) and Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atom-editor

I have a Bitbucket account and with my Mac I'm using Atom for developing PHP.
Is it possible to use Bitbucket in Atom to push my project?

Comment: Generally, you can. What is stopping you? What functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Hi, I can't find an example for configure my Bitbucket and push my files. I can't set it up.